# PHP Money Format

Tags: php, mysql, string, format

Basically, I need a function to help me achieve this:

I have a raw integer, say `5000`, which is an amount of money. It's not formatted in any way. I want to be able to convert `5000` into a string like `"$5k"`.

If the amount was `1000000` (one million), the string would be `"$1m"`.
If the amount was `1000000000` (one billion), the string would be `"$1b"`;

I also need to round the number, so say the amount was `5555555`, the string would be `"$5.5m"`

Comment: Please show us your code. What have you tried so far?  What's not working or where are you stuck?

Comment: Some simple if's plus `round` will do the job for you.

Comment: Nevermind guys, got the code I had working, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

A simple way to do that id to create a format function like this :

```
function format($amount) {

    if ($amount < 1000) {
        return '$' . $amount;
    } else if($amount < 1000000) {
        $amount /= 1000;
        return '$' . round($amount, 1) . 'k';
    } else if($amount < 1000000000) {
        $amount /= 1000000;
        return '$' . round($amount, 1) . 'm';
    } else {
        $amount /= 1000000000;
        return '$' . round($amount, 1) . 'b';
    }
}
```

If you're running PHP on a system with strfmon capabilities, you can use the [money_format](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php) method (windows don't support it).